# Hide File Input After Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a form that allows users to choose a picture from disk for upload and then view a preview of that image.  The user also has the option to add more pictures via a dynamically generated file input appended to the image.  I am using bootstrap-filestyle to make the inputs pretty.

My question is:  can I hide the file input that the user used to select a file after they populate it?  The purpose of this is to bring focus to the newly generated file input.  I have attempted setting the visibility and display via css but neither works.  Perhaps this is related to Bootstrap-Filestyle overlays?

Comment: This works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7sT7D/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Say you have this element:

`<input type='file' id='file_upload'>`

You could use the following jQuery to hide it when a file is selected

```
$('#file_upload').change(function() {
  $('#file_upload').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Your solution works, but I forgot to mention that I was using Bootstrap-Filestyle as a file input overlay.  Do you think that's why its not behaving as expected?

Comment: It's possible. Depending on what classes you were adding to try and get it to hide, the bootstrap selectors could have been overriding it

Comment: Yes it was an issue with filestyle.  To get it to hide, I had to do:

    $('#myfile').filestyle('destroy');
    $('#myfile').hide();  Thanks again for the help.